# Difference between dask pivot_table and pandas pivot_table python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, dask

It seems we can achieve same goal using pivot_table from both libraries, but which one is more efficient in performance for large dataset?

Comment: What is "large"? :)

Comment: 2 million rows and 2k columns approx after pivoting.

Comment: I was thinking more bytes in, bytes out.

Comment: In any case, the only way you can know for *sure* is to try it with your situation, and keep in mind that Dask has options on how you set things up (threads, processes, or a mixture...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely Dask. The way pandas work is, it processes everything as a monolithic block in memory and is not parallelizable, while Dask is made to break the data frame into chunks that can be processed in parallel.